# How to parse this date: 2017-11-28T23:00:00Z in custom Integromat app?

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

Does someone have complete solution how to parse this date: `2017-11-28T23:00:00Z`?

Comment: Plz read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the only format that does not need to be parsed manually is the one that includes milliseconds: `2017-11-28T23:00:00.000Z`.

In your specific case, use `parseDate(your-date-field; YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ)`.
The date/time parsing tokens are explained [here](https://support.integromat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005688594-Tokens-for-date-time-parsing).